# Re-frame db organization

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

We have our Re-frame app db organized like this (simplified for this post):

```
{:meta {:page/search {:page/component #'...} :page/details {:page/component #'...}}
 :widget/base {:cur-page-id :page/search}
 :page/search {:page/route {:query-params {:q "1"}, ...}, 
 :page/details {:page/route {:query-params {:q "2"}}, ...}
```

Consider everything under `:meta` immutable.

The `base` widget takes care of rendering the currently selected page by subscribing to `[:widget/base :cur-page-id]` and then selecting `[:meta cur-page-id :page/component]`. 
It also needs the `:page/route` of the current page, which the pages themselves also need. It gets this one by subscribing to `(fn [db] (get-in db [cur-page-id :page/route]))`. This may be an anti-pattern because we now have a subscription to the entire db.

We could refactor this, but maybe it’s good to know first what this costs in performance. Is there a way to measure this properly?

We could e.g. store the routes under the `:widget/base` entry where pages would look up their own routes via a subscription that selects only `:widget/base :routes`, avoiding a subscription to the entire db.

Answer (score 0):

For measuring performance of subscriptions https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-trace is recommended.